# Put stars on ggplot barplots and boxplots - to indicate the level of significance (p-value)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, p-value, bar-chart

It's common to put stars on barplots or boxplots to show the level of significance (p-value) of one or between two groups, below are several examples:

[image][image][image]

The number of stars are defined by p-value, for example one can put 3 stars for p-value < 0.001, two stars for p-value < 0.01, and so on (although this changes from one article to the other).

And my questions: How to generate similar charts? The methods that automatically put stars based on significance level are more than welcome.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Can you narrow it down? And perhaps show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Most journals nowadays dislike the star notation, even if some table in R still print these. Check with you journal first.

Comment: the bottom-left one is easy: you set up a data.frame with the positions of those stars and add a geom_text layer with labels "***".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please find my attempt below.

[image: Example plot]

First, I created some dummy data and a barplot which can be modified as we wish.

```
windows(4,4)

dat <- data.frame(Group = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2"),
                  Sub   = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
                  Value = c(3,5,7,8))  

## Define base plot
p <-
ggplot(dat, aes(Group, Value)) +
    theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 15)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey20")) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Sub), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.5)
```

Adding asterisks above a column is easy, as baptiste already mentioned. Just create a `data.frame` with the coordinates.

```
label.df <- data.frame(Group = c("S1", "S2"),
                       Value = c(6, 9))

p + geom_text(data = label.df, label = "***")
```

To add the arcs that indicate a subgroup comparison, I computed parametric coordinates of a half circle and added them connected with `geom_line`. Asterisks need new coordinates, too.

```
label.df <- data.frame(Group = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2),
                       Value = c(6.5,6.8,7.1, 9.5,9.8,10.1))

# Define arc coordinates
r <- 0.15
t <- seq(0, 180, by = 1) * pi / 180
x <- r * cos(t)
y <- r*5 * sin(t)

arc.df <- data.frame(Group = x, Value = y)

p2 <-
p + geom_text(data = label.df, label = "*") +
    geom_line(data = arc.df, aes(Group+1, Value+5.5), lty = 2) +
    geom_line(data = arc.df, aes(Group+2, Value+8.5), lty = 2)
```

Lastly, to indicate comparison between groups, I built a larger circle and flattened it at the top.

```
r <- .5
x <- r * cos(t)
y <- r*4 * sin(t)
y[20:162] <- y[20] # Flattens the arc

arc.df <- data.frame(Group = x, Value = y)

p2 + geom_line(data = arc.df, aes(Group+1.5, Value+11), lty = 2) +
     geom_text(x = 1.5, y = 12, label = "***")
```

Comment: It takes very long time to plot between-groups line in my case. Anyway to speed it up?

Comment: I am trying to replace label = "***" with label = "p=0.02", but the text get very bold, any suggestions?

Comment: this can be set by `size` like: geom_text(size=1)

Comment: usually when text looks very bold the issue is that there are many identical labels being printed one on top of another.

Answer (score 91):

I know that this is an old question and the answer by Jens Tierling already provides one solution for the problem. But I recently created a ggplot-extension that simplifies the whole process of adding significance bars: [ggsignif](https://github.com/Artjom-Metro/ggsignif)

Instead of tediously adding the `geom_line` and `geom_text` to your plot you just add a single layer `geom_signif`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("versicolor", "virginica")), 
              map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

[image: Boxplot with significance bar]

To create a more advanced plot similar to the one shown by Jens Tierling, you can do:

```
dat <- data.frame(Group = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2"),
              Sub   = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
              Value = c(3,5,7,8))  

ggplot(dat, aes(Group, Value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Sub), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.5) +
  geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.875, 1.875), xend=c(1.125, 2.125),
                              y=c(5.8, 8.5), annotation=c("**", "NS")),
              aes(x=x,xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, annotation=annotation)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("S1", "S2")), annotations="***",
              y_position = 9.3, tip_length = 0, vjust=0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", "grey20"))
```

[image]

Full documentation of the package is available at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/index.html).

Comment: Hi. Can I have square brackets (to identify which group is the comparsion) for the second graphic also?

Comment: Sure, just set `tip_length` to something other than 0

Comment: Tks. but it just worked for the second `geom_signif`, not for the first one (the one that contains the `data.frame`.

Comment: Interesting, that is not how it's supposed to be... Would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues with a small reproducible example. I would take a look then ant try to figure out what is happening :)

Comment: problem is that you can only use the implemented statistical test, which probably is some simple mean comparison. Many disciplines cannot work with these simple tests when comparing two groups.

Comment: @Jaynes01, this incorrect. With the `test` argument you can call any test that you want.

Comment: Ok, so you can fit a model that I otherwise can only build in Stan (because there is no ready made package to create it) in the geom_signif function? It would be better to also have an option to add stars for more complex tests or even for alternative decision criteria (other than p-values).

Answer (score 40):

There is also an extension of the [ggsignif](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/index.html) package called [ggpubr](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots#compare-more-than-two-groups) that is more powerful when it comes to multi-group comparisons. It builds on top of ggsignif, but also handles anova and kruskal-wallis as well as pairwise comparisons against the gobal mean.

Example:

```
library(ggpubr)

my_comparisons = list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )

ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
          color = "dose", palette = "jco")+ 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = c(29, 35, 40))+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 45)
```

[image]

Comment: This might be a screenshot from this site: (very useful site, too) https://www.r-bloggers.com/add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/

Comment: But how to combine with `geom_boxplot` from`ggplot`?

Comment: Please, how can you plot the significance level (***) instead of the p-values? This example does not show this. Thank you!

Comment: @maycca I've updated my answer to use stars instead.

Answer (score 6):

I found [this one](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggpval/man/add_pval.html) is useful.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpval)
data("PlantGrowth")
plt <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(group, weight)) +
  geom_boxplot()
add_pval(plt, pairs = list(c(1, 3)), test='wilcox.test')
```

Answer (score 3):

Made my own function:

```
ts_test <- function(dataL,x,y,method="t.test",idCol=NULL,paired=F,label = "p.signif",p.adjust.method="none",alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),...) {
    options(scipen = 999)

    annoList <- list()

    setDT(dataL)

    if(paired) {
        allSubs <- dataL[,.SD,.SDcols=idCol] %>% na.omit %>% unique
        dataL   <- dataL[,merge(.SD,allSubs,by=idCol,all=T),by=x]  #idCol!!!
    }

    if(method =="t.test") {
        dataA <- eval(parse(text=paste0(
                       "dataL[,.(",as.name(y),"=mean(get(y),na.rm=T),sd=sd(get(y),na.rm=T)),by=x] %>% setDF"
                       )))
        res<-pairwise.t.test(x=dataL[[y]], g=dataL[[x]], p.adjust.method = p.adjust.method,
                        pool.sd = !paired, paired = paired,
                        alternative = alternative, ...)
    }

    if(method =="wilcox.test") {
        dataA <- eval(parse(text=paste0(
            "dataL[,.(",as.name(y),"=median(get(y),na.rm=T),sd=IQR(get(y),na.rm=T,type=6)),by=x] %>% setDF"
        )))
        res<-pairwise.wilcox.test(x=dataL[[y]], g=dataL[[x]], p.adjust.method = p.adjust.method,
                             paired = paired, ...)
    }

    #Output the groups
    res$p.value %>% dimnames %>%  {paste(.[[2]],.[[1]],sep="_")} %>% cat("Groups ",.)

    #Make annotations ready
    annoList[["label"]] <- res$p.value %>% diag %>% round(5)

    if(!is.null(label)) {
        if(label == "p.signif"){
            annoList[["label"]] %<>% cut(.,breaks = c(-0.1, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1),
                                         labels = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns")) %>% as.character
        }
    }

    annoList[["x"]] <- dataA[[x]] %>% {diff(.)/2 + .[-length(.)]}
    annoList[["y"]] <- {dataA[[y]] + dataA[["sd"]]} %>% {pmax(lag(.), .)} %>% na.omit

    #Make plot
    coli="#0099ff";sizei=1.3

    p <-ggplot(dataA, aes(x=get(x), y=get(y))) + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=len-sd, ymax=len+sd),width=.1,color=coli,size=sizei) +
        geom_line(color=coli,size=sizei) + geom_point(color=coli,size=sizei) + 
        scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme_minimal() +
        xlab(x) + ylab(y) + ggtitle("title","subtitle")


    #Annotate significances
    p <-p + annotate("text", x = annoList[["x"]], y = annoList[["y"]], label = annoList[["label"]])

    return(p)
}
```

## Data and call:

```
library(ggplot2);library(data.table);library(magrittr);

df_long    <- rbind(ToothGrowth[,-2],data.frame(len=40:50,dose=3.0))
df_long$ID <- data.table::rowid(df_long$dose)

ts_test(dataL=df_long,x="dose",y="len",idCol="ID",method="wilcox.test",paired=T)
```

## Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a simple tool in the library `superb` call `showSignificance` which allows you to put whatever text you want, horizontally or vertically. For example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(superb)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  showSignificance( c(1,2), 7.5, -0.05, "**") + 
  showSignificance( c(2,3), 4.5, +0.05, "n.s.") + 
  showSignificance( 3.45, c(6.5,5.9), -0.02, "yup!")
```

[image: Result with Iris dataset]