# R ggplot2: Blank page before plot with pdf() and ggplot_gtable() / ggplot_build()

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I need to modify some annotation of a plot, so I have to save the ggplot2 plot and do

```
ggplot_build(plot.obj)
```

and then plot it with

```
plot(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot.obj)))
```

the problem is, when I save it in a pdf like this

```
pdf(file="test.pdf")
  plot(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(plot.obj)))
dev.off()
```

the resulting pdf has a blank page before the plot page... How can I avoid this?

Check this MWE

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
box <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) +
    ylab("Sepal Length") + ggtitle("Iris Boxplot") +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4) 
box2 <- ggplot_build(box)
#I do stuff here
pdf(file="test.pdf")
  plot(ggplot_gtable(box2))
dev.off()
```

The question would be how to make a pdf with ggplot_gtable without that blank page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this argument `onefile=FALSE` fixes this!

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
box <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) +
  ylab("Sepal Length") + ggtitle("Iris Boxplot") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4) 
box2 <- ggplot_build(box)
#I do stuff here
pdf.options(reset = TRUE, onefile = FALSE)
pdf(file="test.pdf")
my_plot <- plot(ggplot_gtable(box2))
#ggsave("test1.png", plot = my_plot,dev = 'png')
print(my_plot)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hey, this works only for single-page pdf, some hack required for multipage ones!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
plot(ggplot_gtable(box2))
ggsave(filename = "my_plot.pdf")
```