# How to plot significance in ggplot geom_bar() with multiple facets and groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I created a multi-facet plot with 4 groups of 3 bars each in every panel using `ggplot2`.

[image: Main bar plot]

I then ran a separate test to see if there are statistically significant differences between each combination of the bar categories in each age group and in each facet, which produced a separate data.frame `p.val.df`. I now need to figure out how to get significance bars to appear between the bars, just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45050498/7737649) but additionally within each age group. This is where I am running aground. Since I already have my p-values, I don't need to calculate them using `geom_signif()` of the `ggsignif` package, but would rather just use `geom_bracket` of `ggpubr` package to plot them. But any way you could make it work is acceptable.

Here's the data and code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Main data
df <- data.frame(
  factor(rep(c("A1", "A2"), each = 12), levels = c("A1", "A2")),
  factor(rep(c("G", "M", "B"), each = 4), levels = c("G", "M", "B")),
  factor(rep(c("0-2", "3-5", "6-12", "13-17"), 6), levels = c("0-2", "3-5", "6-12", "13-17")),
  c(160, 162, 169, 108, 110, 111, 76, 73, 76, 45, 41, 38, 175, 
    177, 173, 174, 167, 172, 176, 162, 166, 143, 130, 143))

colnames(df) <- c("Class", "Type", "Age", "Coefficient")

# Intergroup difference significance
p.val.df <- data.frame(
  factor(rep(c("A1", "A2"), each = 12), levels = c("A1", "A2")),
  factor(rep(c("G", "M", "G"), each = 4), levels = c("G", "M")),
  factor(rep(c("B", "B", "M"), each = 4), levels = c("B", "M")),
  factor(rep(c("0-2", "3-5", "6-12", "13-17"), 6), levels = c("0-2", "3-5", "6-12", "13-17")),
  c(0.635, 0.584, 0.268, 0.051, 0.163, 0.779, 0.302, 0.361, 0.055, 0.425, 0.998, 0.055,
    0.707, 0.230, 0.000, 0.002, 0.418, 0.313, 0.211, 0.037, 0.675, 0.764, 0.011, 0.881))

colnames(p.val.df) <- c("Class", "Type1", "Type2", "Age", "p.value")

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = Age, y = Coefficient, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  labs(y = "Coefficient", x = "Age", fill = "Type") + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Class, scales = "free") + 
  expand_limits(y = 300) +
  theme_classic() +

### NOT SURE HOW TO PROCEED HERE
 geom_bracket(
    data = p.val.df, y.position = 250, step.increase = 0.1,
    aes(xmin = Type1, xmax = Type2, label = signif(p.value, 2)))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you considered that such a visualisation may get very crowded ? I.e. very difficult to read? Maybe a different type of visualisation (or: statistical approach, e.g. more complex regression models) may be more appropriate. Also, a lot of code is not quite necessary for the question (e.g., the entire calls to `theme` and `scale`).

Comment: @Tjebo Thank you so much. I have considered the fact that these could get crowded, but in actual fact they won't, given that only a few combinations of coefficients are statistically significant. In particular, I need to create these significance brackets in the specific scenario where I don't have access to data on which the post-regression statistics were run, so I only have the data with coefficients to plot and then a separate file with corresponding p-values. I agree that calls to ```theme``` and ```scale``` are not strictly required, but I would leave it to the discretion of the users.

Comment: Less is more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - reducing your code to the essential is not only courtesy to us who want to help, but it makes it much more likely that we are actually going to help

Comment: Based on this issue https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/65 , a good workaround might be to plot Type on the x-axis, use Age as your legend (3 sets of 4 bars vs 4 sets of 3 bars), and then follow their method for displaying p values

Comment: Hi @DenysD. did you get this working in the end? I'm struggling with the same issue!

Comment: @DS14 Unfortunately, no. There are ways to make the brackets appear between the x categories, but not within them (if there are multiple groups, like in my case). At least, I wasn't able to find any reasonable solution that would not be more effort than it's worth. I am still curious to see if someone has come up with a solution.

Comment: @DenysD. Shame! I'm dealing with the same issue - 4 different groups faceted by sex. (so 8 bars in total). I love the way my figure looks and I'm able to add all the other stats within the facets. I have a temporary work-around where I add significance values with a dot rather than an asterisk over the bars in one facet to denote differences between males and females. Not ideal but it gets the point across.