# ggplot2 boxplots - How to avoid extra vertical space when there are no significant comparisons?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After many questions on how to make boxplots with facets and significance levels, particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476950/r-ggplot2-boxplots-ggpubr-stat-compare-means-not-working-properly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446392/r-ggplot2-boxplots-with-significance-level-more-than-2-groups-kruskal-test-an), I still have one more little problem.

I managed to produce the plot shown below, which is exactly what I want.

The problem I am facing now is when I have very few, or no significant comparisons; in those cases, the whole space dedicated to the brackets showing the significance levels is still preserved, but I want to get rid of it.

Please check this MWE with the iris dataset:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
iris$treatment <- rep(c("A","B"), length(iris$Species)/2)
mydf <- melt(iris, measure.vars=names(iris)[1:4])
mydf$treatment <- as.factor(mydf$treatment)
mydf$variable <- factor(mydf$variable, levels=sort(levels(mydf$variable)))
mydf$both <- factor(paste(mydf$treatment, mydf$variable), levels=(unique(paste(mydf$treatment, mydf$variable))))
a <- combn(levels(mydf$both), 2, simplify = FALSE)#this 6 times, for each lipid class
b <- levels(mydf$Species)
CNb <- relist(
    paste(unlist(a), rep(b, each=sum(lengths(a)))), 
    rep.int(a, length(b))
)
CNb
CNb2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(CNb), ncol=2, byrow=T))
CNb2
#new p.values
pv.df <- data.frame()
for (gr in unique(mydf$Species)){
    for (i in 1:length(a)){
        tis <- a[[i]] #variable pair to test
        as <- subset(mydf, Species==gr & both %in% tis)
        pv <- wilcox.test(value ~ both, data=as)$p.value
        ddd <- data.table(as)
        asm <- as.data.frame(ddd[, list(value=mean(value)), by=list(both=both)])
        asm2 <- dcast(asm, .~both, value.var="value")[,-1]
        pf <- data.frame(group1=paste(tis[1], gr), group2=paste(tis[2], gr), mean.group1=asm2[,1], mean.group2=asm2[,2], log.FC.1over2=log2(asm2[,1]/asm2[,2]), p.value=pv)
        pv.df <- rbind(pv.df, pf)
    }
}
pv.df$p.adjust <- p.adjust(pv.df$p.value, method="BH")
colnames(CNb2) <- colnames(pv.df)[1:2]
# merge with the CN list
pv.final <- merge(CNb2, pv.df, by.x = c("group1", "group2"), by.y = c("group1", "group2"))
# fix ordering
pv.final <- pv.final[match(paste(CNb2$group1, CNb2$group2), paste(pv.final$group1, pv.final$group2)),]
# set signif level
pv.final$map.signif <- ifelse(pv.final$p.adjust > 0.05, "", ifelse(pv.final$p.adjust > 0.01,"*", "**"))
# subset
G <- pv.final$p.adjust <= 0.05
CNb[G]
P <- ggplot(mydf,aes(x=both, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) +
    facet_grid(~Species, scales="free", space="free_x") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
    geom_signif(test="wilcox.test", comparisons = combn(levels(mydf$both),2, simplify = F),
              map_signif_level = F,            
              vjust=0.5,
              textsize=4,
              size=0.5,
              step_increase = 0.06)
P2 <- ggplot_build(P)

#pv.final$map.signif <- "" #UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO MOCK A CASE WHERE THERE ARE NO SIGNIFICANT COMPARISONS
#pv.final$map.signif[c(1:42,44:80,82:84)] <- "" #UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO MOCK A CASE WHERE THERE ARE JUST A COUPLE OF SIGNIFICANT COMPARISONS

P2$data[[2]]$annotation <- rep(pv.final$map.signif, each=3)
# remove non significants
P2$data[[2]] <- P2$data[[2]][P2$data[[2]]$annotation != "",]
# and the final plot
png(filename="test.png", height=800, width=800)
  plot(ggplot_gtable(P2))
dev.off()
```

Which produces this plot:

[image: test1]

The plot above is exactly what I want... But I am facing cases where there are no significant comparisons, or very few. In these cases, a lot of vertical space is left empty.

To exemplify those scenarios, we can uncomment the line:

```
pv.final$map.signif <- "" #UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO MOCK A CASE WHERE THERE ARE NO SIGNIFICANT COMPARISONS
```

So when there are no significant comparisons I get this plot:

[image: test2]

If we uncomment this other line instead:

```
pv.final$map.signif[c(1:42,44:80,82:84)] <- "" #UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO MOCK A CASE WHERE THERE ARE JUST A COUPLE OF SIGNIFICANT COMPARISONS
```

We are in a case where there are only a couple of significant comparisons, and obtain this plot:

[image: test3]

So my question here is:

How to adjust the vertical space to the number of significant comparisons, so no vertical space is left there?

There might be something I could change in `step_increase` or in `y_position` inside `geom_signif()`, so I only leave space for the significant comparisons in `CNb[G]`...

Comment: It seems that the last example in the first link you cite exactly does/shows what you want, so why not reduce your example to something similar and see if you can reproduce that figure and then build back up to your complete data?

Comment: That is not the case... in that link the answer dos not hide non-significant comparisons, that's why I need to do the tests outside the plot and then change the plot's annotation (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552715/r-ggplot2-perform-pairwise-tests-per-pair-in-a-facet-and-show-the-p-values-wit)

Comment: But you are onto something... As in the first link I provide, I can probably do `comparisons=CNb[G]` inside `geom_signif()` instead... and that would leave space only for the significant comparisons hopefully... let me try and get back to you

Comment: @DaniCee It did not work, I have attempted it :(

Comment: Nothing I have tried so far works... Any of you guys have a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option is to pre-calculate the p-values for each combination of `both` levels and then select only the significant ones for plotting. Since we then know up front how many are significant, we can adjust the y-ranges of the plots to account for that. However, it doesn't look like `geom_signif` is capable of doing only within-facet calculations for the p-value annotations (see the help for the `manual` argument). Thus, instead of using ggplot's faceting, we instead use `lapply` to create a separate plot for each `Species` and then use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package to lay out the individual plots as if they were faceted.

(To respond to the comments, I want to emphasize that the plots are all still created with ggplot2, but we create what would have been the three facet panels of a single plot as *three separate plots* and then lay them out together as if they had been faceted.)

The function below is hard-coded for the data frame and column names in the OP, but can of course be generalized to take any data frame and column names.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)

# Change data to reduce number of statistically significant differences
set.seed(2)
df = mydf %>% mutate(value=rnorm(nrow(mydf)))

# Function to generate and lay out the plots
signif_plot = function(signif.cutoff=0.05, height.factor=0.23) {

  # Get full range of y-values
  y_rng = range(df$value)

  # Generate a list of three plots, one for each Species (these are the facets)
  plot_list = lapply(split(df, df$Species), function(d) {

    # Get pairs of x-values for current facet
    pairs = combn(sort(as.character(unique(d$both))), 2, simplify=FALSE)

    # Run wilcox test on every pair
    w.tst =  pairs %>% 
      map_df(function(lv) { 
        p.value = wilcox.test(d$value[d$both==lv[1]], d$value[d$both==lv[2]])$p.value
        data.frame(levs=paste(lv, collapse=" "), p.value)
      })

    # Record number of significant p.values. We'll use this later to adjust the top of the
    # y-range of the plots
    num_signif = sum(w.tst$p.value <= signif.cutoff)

    # Plot significance levels only for combinations with p <= signif.cutoff
    p = ggplot(d, aes(x=both, y=value)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      facet_grid(~Species, scales="free", space="free_x") +
      geom_signif(test="wilcox.test", comparisons = pairs[which(w.tst$p.value <= signif.cutoff)],
                  map_signif_level = F,            
                  vjust=0,
                  textsize=3,
                  size=0.5,
                  step_increase = 0.08) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))

    # Return the plot and the number of significant p-values
    return(list(num_signif, p))
  })

  # Get the highest number of significant p-values across all three "facets"
  max_signif = max(sapply(plot_list, function(x) x[[1]]))

  # Lay out the three plots as facets (one for each Species), but adjust so that y-range is same
  # for each facet. Top of y-range is adjusted using max_signif.
  grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(plot_list, function(x) x[[2]] + 
                              scale_y_continuous(limits=c(y_rng[1], y_rng[2] + height.factor*max_signif))), 
               ncol=3, left="Value")
}
```

Now run the function with four different significance cutoffs:

```
signif_plot(0.05)
```

[image]

```
signif_plot(0.01)
```

[image]

```
signif_plot(0.9)
```

[image]

```
signif_plot(0.0015)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to keep this in ggplot2?

Comment: You mean you want to avoid any code other than the ggplot2 code? I think that would require enhancements to `geom_signif` to handle facets natively (by generating significance annotations by facet, rather than adding the same annotations to all facets) and to allow non-plotting of annotations for non-significant tests.

Comment: I would rather stick to ggplot2 if possible for consistency, cause I have all my plots done that way...

Comment: The plotting in my answer is all in ggplot2, but some of the calculations have to be done outside of the actual call to ggplot2.

Comment: Oh ok, let me try and get back to you!

Comment: I get the following error with your code `Error in map_df(., function(lv) { : could not find function "map_df"`... Is it possible to use `*` and `**`? Will doing `map_signif_level` just work?

Comment: Looking at the last two examples in the following link, do you think there might be a way to do it keeping it as similar as possible to my example?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/README.html

Comment: Maybe just reformating `pv.final2` (so it looks somewhat like `annotation_df` in the link above) after doing `pv.final2 <- subset(pv.final, p.adjust<=0.05)` and passing it to `geom_signif` might work

Comment: Regarding the `Error in map_df...`: I forgot to include the `purrr` package in my code. I've fixed that by adding `library(tidyverse)`, which loads `ggplot2`, `purrr`, and several other related packages that are all part of the `tidyverse`.

Comment: Please have a look at the following question I just posted. I accepted your answer here, but I still find problematic to color the boxplots, show asterisks instead of numbers, and have a legend, as I wanted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783163/r-ggplot2-boxplots-with-wilcoxon-significance-levels-and-facets-show-only-sig

Answer (score 0):

You can try. Although the answer is similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580556/ggplot2-boxplots-how-to-avoid-extra-vertical-space-when-there-are-no-significa/46637005?noredirect=1#comment80242062_46637005), I added now a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
# 1. your data
set.seed(2)
df <- as.tbl(iris) %>% 
  mutate(treatment=rep(c("A","B"), length(iris$Species)/2)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Species, -treatment) %>% 
  mutate(value=rnorm(n())) %>% 
  mutate(key=factor(key, levels=unique(key))) %>% 
  mutate(both=interaction(treatment, key, sep = " "))

# 2. pairwise.wilcox.test for 1) validation and 2) to calculate the ylim
Wilcox <- df %>% 
  split(., .$Species) %>% 
  map(~tidy(pairwise.wilcox.test(.$value, .$both, p.adjust.method =  "none"))) %>% 
  map(~filter(.,.$p.value < 0.05)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id="Species") %>% 
  mutate(padjust=p.adjust(p.value, method = "BH"))

# 3. calculate y range
Ylim <- df %>% 
  summarise(Min=round(min(value)),
            Max=round(max(value))) %>% 
  mutate(Max=Max+0.5*group_by(Wilcox, Species) %>% count() %>% with(.,max(n))) 
  %>% c()

# 4. the plot function 
foo <- function(df, Ylim, Signif=0.05){
P <- df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=both, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Species)) + 
  facet_grid(~Species) +
  ylim(Ylim$Min, Ylim$Max)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = combn(levels(df$both),2,simplify = F),
              map_signif_level = F, test = "wilcox.test" ) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=4) +
  xlab("") 
# 5. remove not significant values and add step increase
P_new <- ggplot_build(P)
P_new$data[[2]] <- P_new$data[[2]] %>% 
  filter(as.numeric(as.character(annotation)) < 0.05) %>% 
  group_by(PANEL) %>%
  mutate(index=(as.numeric(group[drop=T])-1)*0.5) %>% 
  mutate(y=y+index,
         yend=yend+index) %>% 
  select(-index) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
# the final plot  
plot(ggplot_gtable(P_new))
}

foo(df, Ylim)
```

[image]

trying other data

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- as.tbl(iris) %>% 
  mutate(treatment=rep(c("A","B"), length(iris$Species)/2)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Species, -treatment) %>% 
  mutate(value=rnorm(n())) %>% 
  mutate(key=factor(key, levels=unique(key))) %>% 
  mutate(both=interaction(treatment, key, sep = " "))

foo(df, list(Min=-3,Max=5))
```

[image]

Ofcourse you can add the Ylim calculation to the function as well. In addition you can change or add `ggtitel()`, `ylab()` and change the color.