# How to add wilcox.test pvalue to a Facet_nested ggplot object (using geom_signif for example ?)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, p-value

I am trying to build a `facet_nested` ggplot in which I could add `Wilcox.test` results between pairs of `scenarios`.

I have the following data frame :

```
structure(list(scenario = c("DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", 
"DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", 
"DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", 
"DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", 
"DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", 
"DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG DB-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", 
"DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", 
"DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", 
"DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", 
"DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", 
"DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "DEG R-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", 
"Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", 
"Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", 
"Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", 
"Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", 
"Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var DB-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", 
"Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", 
"Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", 
"Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", 
"Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S", 
"Var R-S", "Var R-S", "Var R-S"), replicates = c("A_S10x", "A_S1x", 
"A_S2x", "A_S3x", "A_S4x", "A_S5x", "A_S6x", "A_S7x", "A_S8x", 
"A_S9x", "B_S10x", "B_S1x", "B_S2x", "B_S3x", "B_S4x", "B_S5x", 
"B_S6x", "B_S7x", "B_S8x", "B_S9x", "C_S10x", "C_S1x", "C_S2x", 
"C_S3x", "C_S4x", "C_S5x", "C_S6x", "C_S7x", "C_S8x", "C_S9x", 
"A_S10x", "A_S1x", "A_S2x", "A_S3x", "A_S4x", "A_S5x", "A_S6x", 
"A_S7x", "A_S8x", "A_S9x", "B_S10x", "B_S1x", "B_S2x", "B_S3x", 
"B_S4x", "B_S5x", "B_S6x", "B_S7x", "B_S8x", "B_S9x", "C_S10x", 
"C_S1x", "C_S2x", "C_S3x", "C_S4x", "C_S5x", "C_S6x", "C_S7x", 
"C_S8x", "C_S9x", "A_S10x", "A_S1x", "A_S2x", "A_S3x", "A_S4x", 
"A_S5x", "A_S6x", "A_S7x", "A_S8x", "A_S9x", "B_S10x", "B_S1x", 
"B_S2x", "B_S3x", "B_S4x", "B_S5x", "B_S6x", "B_S7x", "B_S8x", 
"B_S9x", "C_S10x", "C_S1x", "C_S2x", "C_S3x", "C_S4x", "C_S5x", 
"C_S6x", "C_S7x", "C_S8x", "C_S9x", "A_S10x", "A_S1x", "A_S2x", 
"A_S3x", "A_S4x", "A_S5x", "A_S6x", "A_S7x", "A_S8x", "A_S9x", 
"B_S10x", "B_S1x", "B_S2x", "B_S3x", "B_S4x", "B_S5x", "B_S6x", 
"B_S7x", "B_S8x", "B_S9x", "C_S10x", "C_S1x", "C_S2x", "C_S3x", 
"C_S4x", "C_S5x", "C_S6x", "C_S7x", "C_S8x", "C_S9x"), subspecies = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), species_name = c("Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_1", 
"Species_1", "Species_1", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", "Species_2", 
"Species_2", "Species_2"), condition = c("DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", 
"DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", 
"DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_A", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", 
"DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", 
"DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_B", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", 
"DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", 
"DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG DB-S_C", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", 
"DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", 
"DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_A", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", 
"DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", 
"DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_B", "DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", 
"DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", 
"DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", "DEG R-S_C", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", 
"Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", 
"Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_A", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", 
"Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", 
"Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_B", "Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", 
"Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", 
"Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", "Var DB-S_C", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", 
"Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", 
"Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_A", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", 
"Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", 
"Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_B", "Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", 
"Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", 
"Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C", "Var R-S_C"), value = c(0.98172, 0.978652916666667, 
0.99991, 0.97994, 0.993644583333333, 0.95744375, 0.980380833333333, 
0.998727083333333, 0.984138333333333, 0.995765, 0.988333333333333, 
0.992666666666667, 1, 0.984333333333333, 0.99, 0.960333333333333, 
0.991666666666667, 0.984, 0.994, 0.990666666666667, 0.665374727668845, 
0.662200873362445, 0.664629955947137, 0.65590989010989, 0.667090507726269, 
0.663162790697674, 0.67621412803532, 0.657115044247788, 0.667743929359823, 
0.670337004405286, 0.992484583333333, 0.99117625, 0.997137916666667, 
0.971002083333333, 0.992359166666667, 0.984022916666667, 0.976832083333333, 
0.99386, 0.990916666666667, 0.99885625, 1, 1, 0.996666666666667, 
0.989666666666667, 0.998666666666667, 0.994666666666667, 0.991666666666667, 
0.998, 0.999333333333333, 1, 0.659840611353712, 0.673435164835165, 
0.663804772234273, 0.661091703056769, 0.652524017467249, 0.667353846153846, 
0.664973509933775, 0.660403050108932, 0.666209713024283, 0.667819383259912, 
0.865045416666667, 0.834530833333333, 0.826324583333333, 0.837911666666667, 
0.805854166666667, 0.83401875, 0.79532875, 0.830845416666667, 
0.830444583333333, 0.866255, 0.856666666666667, 0.837, 0.832, 
0.840333333333333, 0.793, 0.832666666666667, 0.802, 0.849666666666667, 
0.859333333333333, 0.877666666666667, 0.533706018518519, 0.491011764705882, 
0.496581395348837, 0.513160465116279, 0.496923627684964, 0.50288056206089, 
0.485009367681499, 0.501932084309133, 0.501605568445476, 0.516875, 
0.828203333333333, 0.831938333333333, 0.83821875, 0.838965833333333, 
0.8511625, 0.8356775, 0.820040416666667, 0.83255625, 0.8550125, 
0.830418333333333, 0.853333333333333, 0.845, 0.864666666666667, 
0.850333333333333, 0.858, 0.828666666666667, 0.831, 0.854333333333333, 
0.856666666666667, 0.857666666666667, 0.518638051044084, 0.504856812933025, 
0.472275294117647, 0.498741258741259, 0.49295337995338, 0.480641330166271, 
0.494142523364486, 0.486962877030162, 0.518133640552995, 0.501102870813397
)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a subset of my original dataframe.

For now and following part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783163/boxplots-with-wilcoxon-significance-levels-and-facets-show-only-significant-co) I manage to get this plot :

[Actual boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn7cB.png)

And for that I used this code :

```
ggplot(copy2, aes(x=scenario, y=value, color=subspecies)) + 
          geom_boxplot(lwd = 0.4, fatten = 1)+
          facet_nested(.~species_name+subspecies,
                                          labeller = label_wrap_gen(5),
                                          strip = strip_nested(size = "variable"),
                                          scales = "free",
                                          space='free')+
          scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1),limits = c(0, 1.1))+
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=70,hjust=1,vjust=1,face="plain"))+
     geom_signif(test='wilcox.test', comparisons = combn(levels(copy$scenario),2,simplify = F),
                 map_signif_level = T)
```

I don't understand why I only have 6 (I think ?) comparisons (and why especially these ones ?) when I should have much more.

Ideally, in each panel of the `facet_nested` plot (example : The panel Species_1 -> A) I would like to get `wilcox.test` results of 4 pairs of comparisons such as :

```
DEG DB-S vs DEG R-S
Var DB-S vs Var R-S
DEG DB-S vs Var DB-S
DEG R-S vs Var R-S
```

Those are values contained in my `scenario` variable.

I know that in my data frame I'm supposed to have all variable to do what I want but I don't know how to use them.
I would prefer achieve it using `geom_signif` but of course I am open to every solutions that could help me.

Thank you a lot in advance for your time,

Elsa