# Connect two boxplots to show significance in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I would like to connect two boxplots to show if they are significant in an external association analysis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
head(ToothGrowth)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]
Let's assume that the dose `0.5` is significantly different from both dose `1` and `2`. Thus, I would expect something like this:

[image]

Any idea how to draw it in ggplot2 in a smart way using `ggplot2`? I am aware about this post: [Indicating significance with ggplot2, in a boxplot with multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839988/indicating-significance-with-ggplot2-in-a-boxplot-with-multiple-groups). However, it seems to work only when you run the analysis on the fly.

Comment: And this post? (possible duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084566/put-stars-on-ggplot-barplots-and-boxplots-to-indicate-the-level-of-significanc

Comment: As far I can see, most of the alternatives run the analysis on the fly. I am looking for a fully customized notation. Maybe I failed to see an answer in the recommended post.

Comment: Please check `ggsignif` answer in the linked post (IMO right now this is the most easy to use tool for those kind of problems in ggplot2)