# What to do when adding asterisks to bar graph shifts the bars in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, significance

I've created a bar graph in R and now I tried to add the significant differences to the bar graph.

I've tried using `geom_signif` from the ggsignif package and `stat_compare_means` from the ggpubr package (based on these suggestions/examples: [Put stars on ggplot barplots and boxplots - to indicate the level of significance (p-value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084566/put-stars-on-ggplot-barplots-and-boxplots-to-indicate-the-level-of-significanc) or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html)

I was only able to add the significance levels when using `geom_signif` and choose the parameters as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html.

This is an example of what I would like to get:

[image: Planned bar graphs]

And this is what I get:

[image: Eventual bar graphs]

So when I want to add the asterisks, it shifts the bars from the bar graph. I don't know how to change it...

This is a part of what I wrote:

```
bargraph = ggplot(dataPlotROI, aes(x = ROI, y=mean, fill = Group))

bargraph + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(.5), width = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), width = .2, 
                aes(ymin = mean-SEM, ymax = mean+SEM)) +
  geom_signif(y_position = c(4.5,10,10), xmin=c(0.85,0.85,4.3), xmax = c(5,4,7.45),
              annotation=c("***"), tip_length = 0.03, inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  facet_grid(.~ROI, space= "free_x", scales = "free_x", switch = "x")
```

This is the output from `dput(dataPlotROI)`:

```
> Dput <- dput(dataPlotROI)
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), ROI = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("LOT", "MO", "ROT"), class = "factor"), mean = c(2.56175803333696, 
7.50825658538044, 3.34290874605435, 2.41750375190217, 6.90310020776087, 
3.03040666678261), SD = c(1.15192431061913, 4.30564383354597, 
2.01581544982848, 1.11404900115086, 3.35276625079825, 1.23786817391241
), SEM = c(0.120096411333424, 0.448894400545147, 0.210163288684092, 
0.11614763735292, 0.349550045127766, 0.129056678481624)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
> Dput
  Group ROI     mean       SD       SEM
1     1 LOT 2.561758 1.151924 0.1200964
2     1  MO 7.508257 4.305644 0.4488944
3     1 ROT 3.342909 2.015815 0.2101633
4     2 LOT 2.417504 1.114049 0.1161476
5     2  MO 6.903100 3.352766 0.3495500
6     2 ROT 3.030407 1.237868 0.1290567
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the output from `dput(dataPlotROI)` in your question?

Comment: @Z.Lin I added the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `geom_signif` is meant to span across the facets, but in your case, I don't see any real need for facets anyway. See if the following works for you:

```
ggplot(dataPlotROI,
       aes(x = ROI, y = mean, fill = Group)) +

  # geom_col is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.5), width = 0.5) +

  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.5), width = 0.2,
                aes(ymin = mean - SEM, ymax = mean + SEM)) +

  # xmin / xmax positions should match the x-axis labels' positions
  geom_signif(y_position = c(4.5, 10, 10),
              xmin = c(1, 1, 2.05),
              xmax = c(3, 1.95, 3),
              annotation = "***",
              tip_length = 0.03)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: For this graph indeed there's no need for the facets. It's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Just maybe one other question, do you think/know whether it is possible to adjust the position of the asterisks as well? I managed to change the size of the asterisks, but I don't seem to find a possibility to change the position of the asterisks (for example the asterisks that are now in the middle bars, because my colors are darker and make it difficult to see the asterisks)

Comment: I've added this: `annotate("text", label = "***", x = 1.5, y = 4.2, family = "Cambria", color = "black", size = 7.5)` and that works.