# geom_col values out of order

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-text, geom-col

I am new to R. I am having trouble with the ordering of the `geom_text` elements in the below `geom_col` chart.

I believe it has something to do with the `position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")` line, but I am not sure.

Sample code and outputs attached. As you can see, the labels are wrong - `e` and `b` should be switched, as well as `a` and `d`.

Can someone with sharper eyes (and probably a sharper mind) see what the issue is?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(Importance = c("Not important", "Important", "Critical", "Not important", "Important"), Current.Capability = c("Basic", "Undeveloped", "Advanced", "World class", "World class"), Function = c("PM", "Sales", "PM", "Marketing", "Marketing"), Item = c("a","b", "c", "d", "e"))

str(data)
head(data)

width <- 2
position.width <- width - 0.05

ggplot(data, aes(x = Importance, y = Current.Capability, fill=Function)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"), width = width) +
  facet_grid(~Importance, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  geom_text(
    aes(
    label = stringr::str_wrap(Item, 50)), 
    lineheight = 0.7, 
    angle=90, 
    size = 5, 
    hjust=0, 
    vjust=0.5,
    y = 0.5,
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = position.width)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+ 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("Undeveloped", "Basic", "Advanced", "World class")) +
  xlab("Importance") + ylab("Current Capability")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work. Maybe you can try to add `group = Importance` in the aesthetics of `geom_text`. That is, to "explicitly define the grouping structure", see [grouping](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html). Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971783/5193830) is a related case.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Importance, y = Current.Capability, fill=Function)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"), width = width) +
  facet_grid(~Importance, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = stringr::str_wrap(Item, 50),
      group = Importance), # explicitly define the grouping structure
    lineheight = 0.7, 
    angle=90, 
    size = 5, 
    hjust=0, 
    vjust=0.5,
    y = 0.5,
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = position.width)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+ 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("Undeveloped", "Basic", "Advanced", "World class")) +
  xlab("Importance") + ylab("Current Capability")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed related to grouping. I solved it by including in the aes for geom_col, however, not geom_text. But you put me on the right track!

Comment: Hi @BrevanD'Angelo! Cool! You can also include `group = Importance` in the `aes` of `ggplot` directly, like `ggplot(data, aes(..., group = Importance))` and will also work.